# Prevent Emacs from exiting once the exit procedure has initiated?

Tags: emacs, confirmation, quit

Is there a way to prevent Emacs from exiting once I initiate the exit process?

I occasionally fat finger <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd> as <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>.  It isn't an awful process to get back up and running but I am curious if there is a way I can stop the exit process so that I can continue uninterrupted with all my files open.

Using GNU Emacs 24.3.1. Running on Cygwin under Window 7.

Comment: Even though I accepted scottfrazer's answer, I am thankful for the alternate methods shown.

Comment: I couldn't find this question, so I posted the same question: [a confirmation after C-x C-c before exiting Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/13662/5165).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is a built-in variable you can set to a function like so:

```
(setq confirm-kill-emacs 'y-or-n-p)
```

Comment: By default, Emacs uses `'yes-or-no-p` when you try to exit Emacs and there are unsaved buffers.  For consistency, if you'd like the prompt when closing Emacs to be the same as this default, use `(setq confirm-kill-emacs 'yes-or-n-p)` instead.

Comment: You can set this with customize

Comment: @WalterGR wouldn't `(setq confirm-kill-emacs 'yes-or-no-p)` be more consistent, rather than `(setq confirm-kill-emacs 'yes-or-n-p)`?

Answer (score 3):

scottfrazer's answer's the more appropriate, to me, than what follows.

Enable [Emacs Lock](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ProtectingBuffers) minor mode (`emacs-lock-mode`) on any of the buffers, to prevent Emacs from exiting in case you accidentally hit <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>.

From the Emacs Wiki page:

> Emacs cannot exit until the buffer is killed or unlocked

Add `(emacs-lock-mode)` to your `.emacs`/`init.el` file so that this lock is enabled in every Emacs session. Adding this will lock the `*scratch*` buffer which will have to be unlocked in case you *really* want to exit Emacs.

Another way/hack of doing this is to start a process in Emacs e.g. <kbd>M-x</kbd>`shell` or have an unsaved file associated to a buffer, doing this will prompt you for confirmations when Emacs is exiting.

Yes one more, unset <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> using `global-unset-key`. And then if you want to exit Emacs <kbd>M-x</kbd>`kill-emacs`.

Answer (score 2):

- Using `confirm-kill-emacs`, as @scottfrazer suggested, is one approach.
- More generally, you can use `kill-emacs-query-functions` to do whatever you want in this regard. (There was no real need for them to add `confirm-kill-emacs`, but they did.)
- You probably do not want to use `kill-emacs-hook` in this regard (that's what `kill-emacs-query-functions` is for), but be aware of it, in case you come across it using `apropos` etc.

One advantage of `kill-emacs-query-functions` over just`confirm-kill-emacs` is that you can require a better confirmation: `yes` instead of just hitting key `y`.  For example:

```
(add-hook 'kill-emacs-query-functions
          (lambda () (y-or-n-p "Do you really want to exit Emacs? "))
          'append)
```

That is what I do.  It is too easy to be hitting keys and accidentally hit `C-x C-c y`, especially since I have similar keys bound (e.g., `C-x c`, `C-x C-x`, `C-x C-y`).

Answer (score 2):

I've added the following to my emacs configuration to prevent accidental closes. I didn't like having to confirm close emacs for something like a one off commit, but I hate losing my emacs session accidentally while deep in a problem.

This adds a global state flag to emacs describing whether or not it's locked. This flag is set either automatically after emacs is open for 5 minutes, or manually using the `lock-emacs` command. The lock can later be removed manually by using the `unlock-emacs` command.

If emacs is locked, and you attempt to close it (presumably accidentally), emacs will instead give you a message saying that emacs has been locked, and cannot be closed. If it's unlocked, close behaves exactly as it does by default.

```
;; don't close emacs on accident
(setq emacs-locked nil)
(setq confirm-kill-emacs
      (lambda (&rest args)
        (if emacs-locked
            (progn
              (message "%s" "Emacs is locked, and cannot be closed.")
              nil)
            t)
         ))
(defun lock-emacs-silently ()
  (progn
    (setq emacs-locked t))
  )

(defun lock-emacs ()
  "Prevent emacs from being closed."
  (interactive)
  (progn
    (lock-emacs-silently)
    (message "%s" "Emacs is now locked."))
  )
(defun unlock-emacs ()
  "Allow emacs to be closed."
  (interactive)
  (progn
    (setq emacs-locked 'nil)
    (message "%s" "Emacs can now be closed."))
  )
(run-at-time "5 minutes" nil 'lock-emacs-silently)
```

(Open to suggestions on how to make the confirm-kill-emacs portion nicer, I'm a lisp novice :) ).

---

After using this for a couple of years, I ended up going to something much simpler:

```
;; Unbind the normal close
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-x C-c"))
;; Require C-c 3 times before closing
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-c C-c C-c") 'save-buffers-kill-terminal)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a shorter answer, I've had this line at the bottom of all my .emacs files since the last century:

```
(shell)
```

Comment: Can you explain what adding (shell) does?  I'm searching through the emacs wiki and just searching "shell" is a bit ambiguous to find out what this does.

Comment: I have mentioned it in my answer. `(shell)` actually starts a process which Emacs will prompt you for being active and if you really want to exit. [Shell Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShellMode).